# Multilayer perceptron on C#

Tags: c#, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to make a multilayer perceptron that can output XOR correctly.

I have the following problem. Please look at my neural network, tell me where my mistake is, why my neural network converges to the answer 0.45?

Weights I check, overflow I didn't find, everywhere the weights are less than 1 so most likely it's not paralysis of the neural network. If you need to clarify something, feel free to write.

**Error graph:**

[image]

**Abs(Error) graph:**
[image]

***Note:***

> 1. I have bias everywhere 1
> 2. The slower the learning rate, the slower it converges to 0.45

```
//Feed - forward computation
Layers[i].neurons[j].input = 0; Layers[i].neurons[j].output = 0;
for (int k = 0; k < Layers[i].neurons[j].weights.Count; k++)
{
  Layers[i].neurons[j].input += Layers[i].neurons[j].weights[k].weigth * Layers[i].neurons[j].weights[k].neuronFrom.output;
}
Layers[i].neurons[j].output = Layers[i].activation(Layers[i].neurons[j].input + Layers[i].neurons[j].bias);

//backpropagation to the output layer    
for (int k = 0; k < Layers.Last().neurons.Count; k++)
{
  Layers.Last().neurons[k].error = Layers.Last().neurons[k].output * (1 - Layers.Last().neurons[k].output) * (outputs[i][k] - Layers.Last().neurons[k].output);
}

//backpropagated error to the j-th hidden unit
Double sum = 0;
for (int h = 0; h < Layers[k + 1].neurons.Count; h++)
{
  sum += Layers[k + 1].neurons[h].error * Layers[k + 1].neurons[h].weights[h].weigth;
}
Layers[k].neurons[j].error = Layers[k].neurons[j].output * (1 - Layers[k].neurons[j].output) * sum; 

//Weight updates
for (int h = 0; h < Layers[k].neurons[j].weights.Count; h++)
{
  Layers[k].neurons[j].weights[h].weigth += learningRate * Layers[k].neurons[j].error * Layers[k].neurons[j].output;
}
```